# Asp.net Calendar/Grid with single click entry

Tags: asp.net, input, calendar, scheduler

I'm looking for an asp.net calendar/scheduler control that will allow for single click entry.

I checked out Telerik and a few others but they seem to require double click, and then a prompt, then entry then save.

The control should act like a grid where we could input data, tab between days etc.. making it very easy to populate data for that month

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That's a tough call.  Most calendaring packages that I have seen require a double-click to begin entry from the schedule view.  In this way, the interface can differentiate between selecting a date or time window and attempting to create or edit an entry.

In the Telerik RadScheduler control you could override the OnClientTimeClick event to immediately call Scheduler.showInsertFormAt.  This could give you the single-click effect you are looking for:

```
<telerik:RadScheduler ID="RadScheduler1" runat="server" 
    DayStartTime="05:00:00" DayEndTime="18:00:00" 
    DataKeyField="Id" DataSubjectField="Subject" DataStartField="StartDateTime" DataEndField="EndDateTime"
    OnClientTimeSlotClick="onTimeSlotClick"></telerik:RadScheduler>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function onTimeSlotClick(sender, eventArgs) {
       var scheduler = $find('<%= RadScheduler1.ClientID %>');
       scheduler.showInsertFormAt(eventArgs.get_targetSlot());
    }

  </script>
```